# Why Headless Chrome, Puppeteer running on Lambda gives error on every page.click(), but locally fine?

Tags: aws-lambda, chromium, puppeteer

I am running Lambda function using Puppeteer. I would like to click on  different HTML elements. When I run the code locally it works fine and it clicks, but when I run it on Lambda I am getting :

> Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement

I have set :

```
const browser = await puppeteerLambda.getBrowser({ headless: true, slowMo: 100,  args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--single-process', '--start-fullscreen', '--window-size=1413,749']});     
await page.setViewport({ width: 1413, height: 749 });

 let path = actions.path;
 await page.waitFor(1000);
 clicker = await page.$(path);
 try {
     await clicker.hover();
     await clicker.click();
     await page.waitFor(1500);
 } catch (e) {
   console.log('path click error', e);
   await mailer.mailError(jobName, e);
 }
```

I think it should be available to see the html element with this viewport.
Also I can extract innerText of the click elements. I can click them locally.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it:

```
 clicker = await page.$(path);
 try {
 await page.evaluate((el) => {
     return el.click()
 }, clicker);
 await page.waitFor(1500);
 } catch (e) {
 console.log('click error', e);
 }
```

It's probably bug in *Puppeteer* that can't be done **await clicker.click()**. Also you can always check their [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md).

Comment: So `page.evaluate` worked for this case, but `page.click` cannot, right? Do you know why? Since I'm having the same issue, with `page.click`.